# Flutter Method-Channel

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, smsmanager

I am implementing a Method Channel in Flutter to send textMessage using default messaging app, but it's not working. Rest all programme flow is working fine only the message is not getting sent. Firstly it was trying to send the message but getting the Failed status in the device messaging app and now it is doing nothing.Instead i get this message in Android Studio after my programme flow returns from the channel

**V/PhoneWindow( 5722): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@76c918b, this = DecorView@a148268[MainActivity]**

I just started learning flutter and started learning kotlin
I am testing this code on Xiomi Redmi 6A,API 28

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import android.Manifest
import android.view.View
import android.telephony.SmsManager
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

      private val channel  = "com.myReflectionThoughts/sendConfirmation";

     override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine){
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

    MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger,channel).setMethodCallHandler{
        call,result->
        val arguments = call.arguments<Map<String,Any>>()
        if(call.method == "sendConfirmation"){
        var confirmationMessage = "Your Order has been Accepted !!\n"+"TOD:- "+arguments["Tod"]+" ,Amount:- \u20B9"+arguments["amount"]+" ,Address:- "+arguments["address"]
        requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS),10)

            val smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault()
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(arguments["contact"].toString(),null,confirmationMessage,null,null)
            result.success("Confirmation Sent!!")
        }
        else{
            result.error("Pta nahi","Kuch galat ho gya",null)
        }
    }
    }
}
```

This is the dart file from which i am invoking the MEthodChannel

```
class SwipeOrderTile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SwipeOrderTileState createState() => _SwipeOrderTileState();
}

class _SwipeOrderTileState extends State<SwipeOrderTile> {
  // bool to check if we need to see the order delivery
  bool _showOrderDetails = false;
  Order ord;
  static const platformchannel =
  MethodChannel("com.myReflectionThoughts/sendConfirmation");

  Widget createCustomContainer(dynamic child) {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
        height: 25,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: child);
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final order = Provider.of<Order>(context);
    ord = order;

    return Dismissible(
      key: ValueKey(order.orderId),
      dismissThresholds: {DismissDirection.endToStart: 0.40},
      confirmDismiss: (direction) {
        if (direction == DismissDirection.endToStart)
          // Code To Remove this Order
          return showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (ctx) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: Text(
                    '!! Confirm Action !!',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                  content: Text(
                    'Accept this Order ?',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  actions: [
                    FlatButton(
                        child: Text('Yes',
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          try {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop(false);

                            final dataMap = <String, dynamic>{
                              'Tod': order.timeOfDelivery,
                              'amount': order.amount,
                              'address': order.address,
                              'contactNumber': order.contact
                            };
                         final response = await platformchannel.invokeMethod("sendConfirmation", dataMap);
                             print(response + " DartFile");
                           await Provider.of<RestaurantManager>(context,
                            listen: false)
                            .setOrderStatus(order.serverId, true);
                          } catch (error) {
                            print(error.toString());
                            print("Error Occured while Sending Message");
                          }
                        }),
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text('NO',
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                );
              });
        else {
          return showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (ctx) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: Text(
                    '!! Confirm Action !!',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                  content: Text(
                    'Decline this Order ?',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  actions: [
                    FlatButton(
                        child: Text('Yes'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                          Provider.of<RestaurantManager>(context, listen: false)
                              .setOrderStatus(order.serverId, false);
                        }),
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text('NO'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                );
              });
        }
      },
```